# Accessing members of base classes in the derived class through runtime indexing

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

Consider the following code

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t> struct base {
    std::size_t value;
};

struct derived: base<0>, base<1> {
    using pointer_type = std::size_t derived::*;
    static constexpr std::array<pointer_type, 2> members{{
        &derived::base<0>::value, 
        &derived::base<1>::value
    }};
    constexpr std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept {
        return this->*(members[i]);
    }
    constexpr const std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept {
        return this->*(members[i]);
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    derived x{42, 84};
    std::cout << sizeof(base<0>) + sizeof(base<1>) << " " << sizeof(derived);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It creates a templated structure `base` with a data member `value`, and a structure `derived` that inherits from several specializations of it. I would like to access the `value` of one or the other base class depending on an index provided at runtime. The provided code does not seem to achieve this, and always returns the `value` of the first `base`.

I would like to achieve it:

- Without changing the code of `base`
- Without changing the way `derived` inherits from the `base`
- Without changing the `sizeof(derived)` (tricks should be `constexpr/static`)
- Only using defined behavior (no undefined behavior `reinterpret_cast` for example)
- The access should be in `O(1)` complexity

In other words, the layout of the code that I would like to not change should be:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t> struct base {
    std::size_t value;
};

struct derived: base<0>, base<1> {
    /*  things can be added here */
    constexpr std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept {
        /*  things can be added here */
    }
    constexpr const std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept {
        /*  things can be added here */
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    derived x{42, 84};
    std::cout << sizeof(base<0>) + sizeof(base<1>) << " " << sizeof(derived);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**QUESTION**: Why is the current trick not working, and is there a way to make it work?

**EDIT**: Seems to be a GCC bug. I reported it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95004). Comparison with clang [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KAzBUV).

**EXTRA QUESTION (to language lawyers)**: Is it a GCC bug, or is it undefined behavior according to the C++17 standard?

Comment: The behaviour [differs](https://godbolt.org/z/mUD2Kv) between GCC and Clang.

Comment: I think [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem#2) is pretty clear that this should work, so I vote GCC bug.

Comment: I reported the bug here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a GCC bug. Your original code [produces](https://godbolt.org/z/mUD2Kv) the expected output with Clang.

One workaround for GCC that I was able to find is to turn `members` into a static member function:

```
static constexpr array_type members() noexcept {
    return {&base<0>::value, &base<1>::value};
}

constexpr std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept {
    return this->*members()[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is most probably GCC bug as noted in comments. Nonetheless there is funny workaround for this which using `std::tuple` instead of `std::array`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t> struct base {
    std::size_t value;
};


template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t... Indx>
constexpr auto to_arr_h(const T& val, const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Indx...>) {
    return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Indx)>{val.*(std::get<Indx>(t))...};
}

template<class T, class... Ts>
constexpr auto to_arr(const T& val, const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) {
    return to_arr_h(val, t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}

struct derived: base<0>, base<1> {
    static constexpr auto members = std::make_tuple(&base<0>::value, &base<1>::value);
    constexpr std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept {
        return to_arr(*this, members)[i];
    }
    constexpr const std::size_t& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept {
        return to_arr(*this, members)[i];
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    derived x{42, 84};
    std::cout << sizeof(base<0>) + sizeof(base<1>) << " " << sizeof(derived);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```